# Redirect a page using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am making a simple application to learn jQuery.

I have two pages

- Test1.aspx
- Test2.aspx

On button click event I want to redirect On Test2.aspx with passing some querystring value.

Below is my code, but it's now working:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $.post("Test2.aspx", {
                username: 'one',
                userid: '1'
            }, function (data) {
                window.location = data;
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you including jQuery three times?

Comment: I am new I dont know how to use so I have included all Jquery.

Comment: You need only one, the one from google CDN is good cause users may already have it cached from another site.

Comment: still too much jquery - only need 1

Comment: Thanks all but How to redirect from a page to another page? is there any wrong in my code.

Comment: What does Test2.aspx return? You will have to share that code... for this jquery to work, it should return only the url as text

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It redirects to `/Test.aspx` and encodes `data` object into the query string with [`.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

```
 $("#Button1").click(function () {
    var data = {
        username: 'one',
        userid: '1'
    }
    window.location = "./Test2.aspx?" + $.param(data); //"./Test2.aspx?username=one&userid=1"
});
```

Comment: @Hitesh try with "./Test2.aspx"

Comment: @Hitesh Does yourhost.com/Test2.aspx?username=one&userid=1 work I can't see your server I don't know what the url is supposed to be?

Comment: I have also used                               window.location = "http://localhost:63314/Test2.aspx?"+ $.param(data);

Comment: It would be `window.location = "localhost:63314/Test2.aspx?" + $.param(data);` you have a misplaced semicolon

Comment: Still Not working.. If I run application at local then it not works and if I deploy my website and give full url then it works.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your server give me a url that works. Going to sleep ill respond later